# Desplegar menu hacía la izquierda

Tags: php, html, css

estoy practicando diseñar página web pero sobre el lado derecho quiero desplegar el carrito de compra, pero se sale de la pantalla.

Mi idea es que se despliegue hacía la izquierda y que el carrito quede contra la derecha, pero no encuentro como
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego codigo html:
**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**

CSS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, para pregunats de estilo, debes agregar tu codigo con dicho problema, no una imagen.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu codigo en texto, no como imagen. Saludos

Comment: Léete la norma de como crear un [código mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) por el bien de todos, sobretodo el tuyo si realmente buscas ayuda aqui

Comment: Claramente dije NO UNA IMAGEN... pusiste 3... entiendo que no entendiste XD

Comment: jajjajajaj claramente no tenía ni idea, disculpen!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.